# How are time value comparisons between `timestamp` and `timestamptz` carried out in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

Given the following data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    x timestamp, 
    y timestamptz
)

INSERT INTO tbl(x, y)
VALUES 
('2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-01-01'::timestamptz)
;
```

It's not obvious to me that the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x <> y;
```

Would return a value - given `y` contains timezone information and `x` doesn't.

I'm not sure if this is a general postgres comparison question, or if this is just in relation to timezones.

I thought that `timestamptz` contained additional information, so comparing it with a `timestamp` value would be false. But when thinking about what's actually being compared, I'm not sure, maybe there's a value somewhere else which is just rendered differently within the database (and they are equal), or perhaps postgres implicitly discards timezone information when comparing these values.

Answer (score 1):

`timestamp with time zone` does *not* contain a time zone in PostgreSQL. The UTC offset is added when PostgreSQL displays the value as a string. The UTC offset shown will depend on the current setting of the parameter `timezone`, which every database session should set correctly.

If you compare a `timestamp with time tone` and a `timestamp without time zone` for equality, the UTC offset of the former  will be ignored. So the result of the comparison depends on the current setting of `timezone`.

Comment: Thanks - so are the actual values stored on the DB unix seconds or something? And they are compared (hence equal), but when viewing the data in dbeaver / whatever it's formatted to look like a date with/without timezone info

Comment: The actual storage is in microseconds since 2000-01-01 midnight, where the meaning of "midnight" makes the difference between `timestamp without time zone` and `timestamp with time zone`. PostgreSQL doesn't compare these numerical values, it respects the setting of `timezone`.